# no sound in headphone , ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I am using Asus X450cc. 
some day ago, every things work fine. To day, when i plug my headphone into computer, it does not sound although speaker work perfectly. Some body give me a solution. Thanks . 
PS: I installed pulse audio volume control, when I plug headphone , I can "see" sound, device output is headphone but I do not hear any thing. My headphone works like a charm with other computer .

Answer (score 0):

chose your speakers as the default output or if you use qpaeq use the one it adds as the source output or uninstall pulse and reinstall it this worked for me when my sound sources wouldn't show